# Api-specific tags

Tags: feature-request

It might be useful to have auto-generated tags for each API and add a link to the tag feed to the help page for that API. This would link directly the API documentation with the relevant discussions on SA, create a live FAQ.

For example, the autogenerated tag for the Comments API would be `api-comments`.

**Update:** After browsing the currently existing tags, it looks like most of the APIs already have a tag created for them. However, I still think it'd be helpful if all the API-specific tags were visually different from the general tags (same way as the moderator-only or required tags are) and have a common prefix / are grouped together in the tags list.

Comment: I'd totally ask this one on meta, but we're not supposed to publicly discuss SA yet. :-)

Comment: I wholly support this. A full discovery API is needed.

Comment: er.. what? I don't understand this request

Comment: @Jeff - add a link on the help page for each API that links back to a tag feed specific for that API. For example, http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/stats/help would have a link to http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/stats. A single-click navigation between the API help page and the SA discussions for that particular API.